# Has anyone seen this Elixir/Erlang error?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I've started learning Elixir by reading Dave Thomas' excellent "Programming Elixir" book. I've run into an issue in chapter 13 that I can't make heads or tails of.

I've coded it twice on my Windows 8 machine, and even downloaded the code from pragprog.org. It does run fine under Linux, however, so it seems to be an issue with Windows 8.

```
18:02:35.493 [error] ** State machine #PID<0.135.0> terminating
** Last message in was {:tcp, #Port<0.5676>,
 <<22, 3, 3, 0, 93, 2, 0, 0, 89, 3, 3, 84, 243, 182, 143, 160, 24, 180, 78,      155, 108, 129, 53, 40, 121, 167, 68, 177, 55, 164, 25, 218, 38, 52, 248, 66, 255, 27, 53, 105, 64, 53, 21, 32, 59, 101, 225, 36, ...>>}
** When State == :hello
**      Data  == [data: [{'StateData',
   {:state, :client, {#Reference<0.0.0.779>, #PID<0.118.0>}, :gen_tcp,
:tls_connection, :tcp, :tcp_closed, :tcp_error, 'api.github.com', 443,
#Port<0.5676>,
{:ssl_options, :tls, [{3, 3}, {3, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 0}], :verify_none,
 {#Function<7.50551058/3 in :ssl.handle_verify_options/2>, []},
 #Function<8.50551058/1 in :ssl.handle_verify_options/2>, false, false,
 :undefined, 1, "", '***', "", '***', '***', '***', "", '***', :undefined,
 :undefined, '***', '***',
 [<<192, 36>>, <<192, 40>>, <<192, 38>>, <<192, 42>>, <<0, 107>>,
  <<0, 106>>, <<0, 61>>, <<192, 35>>, <<192, 39>>, <<192, 37>>, <<192, 41>>,
  <<0, 103>>, <<0, ...>>, <<...>>, ...],
 #Function<1.50551058/4 in :ssl.handle_options/1>, true, 268435456, false,
 :undefined, false, :undefined, :undefined, true, :undefined, false},
{:socket_options, :binary, :raw, 0, 0, false}, '***', '***', '***', 49173,
'***', 61467, :ssl_session_cache, {3, 3}, false, :undefined,
{:undefined, :undefined}, :undefined, :undefined, '***', '***', '***',
:undefined, '***', '***', '***', 53273, #Reference<0.0.0.782>, :undefined,
'***', {false, :first}, {#PID<0.118.0>, #Reference<0.0.0.780>},
#Reference<0.0.0.783>, {[], []}, false, true, false, false, :undefined,
:undefined, :undefined}}]]
** Reason for termination =
** {{:badmatch, ""},
 [{:ssl_handshake, :dec_hello_extensions, 2,
   [file: 'ssl_handshake.erl', line: 1737]},
   {:ssl_handshake, :decode_handshake, 3,
   [file: 'ssl_handshake.erl', line: 926]},
  {:tls_handshake, :get_tls_handshake_aux, 3,
   [file: 'tls_handshake.erl', line: 155]},
  {:tls_connection, :next_state, 4, [file: 'tls_connection.erl', line: 433]},
  {:gen_fsm, :handle_msg, 7, [file: 'gen_fsm.erl', line: 503]},
  {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 237]}]}
```

I've also added :ssl/:crypto to my mix.exs, but neither helped.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure it is a duplicate issue, but a fix for the link posted fixed this issue. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Vote to close but only because of accidental duplication.